# Binding DOM elements to Kineticjs drag and drop shapes

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

I've been playing with the Kineticjs library.  I have successfully added the canvas, created a shape and made it drag-and-drop.

I'd like to have html content from the page bound to or wrapped in the shape to be able to make it draggable in the same way, but still retain the interactive functionality in the html/css/jquery (so not caching the html as a bitmap, I thought about that).

I can't see how to do that, perhaps using the id selectors somehow?

Am I approaching it wrong and perhaps there's a simpler method to achieve the same result?

Appreciate any tips, advice or solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after a bit more playing, I gave up looking for ways to use the DOM, and instead, used the built-in text and image objects in kineticjs to recreate the stuff I first created with html/css. It's a bit long winded, would be interested to see if there's a shorter way.

```
// Create the Stage

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container-kinetic',
    width: 1024,
    height: 768
  });

// Start Steve  

// Create the layer
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  // var rectX = stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50;
  // var rectY = stage.getHeight() / 2 - 25;

 // create the group
var group = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: -365,
    y: -275,
    draggable: true
   });

// circle border for object
  var circ = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 43,
    fill: '#fff',
    stroke: '#cccccc',
    strokeWidth: 1,
  });

   // this isn't doing anything - remove in cleanup
    var steve = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
      image: steve,
      width: 81,
      height: 81,
    });

 // add the object title 
   var titleText = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 70,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 55,
    text: 'Steve Schofield - Founder',
    fontSize: 10,
    fontFamily: 'Maven Pro',
    textFill: '#252525'
  });

// add the object image
   var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
     x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 41,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 41,
      image: imageObj,
      width: 81,
      height: 81
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    group.add(yoda);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'img/team_1_p3.png';

 // add the facebook icon
 var imageObjfb = new Image();
  imageObjfb.onload = function() {
    var fbIcon = new Kinetic.Image({
     x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 26,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 82,
      image: imageObjfb,
      width: 8,
      height: 12
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    group.add(fbIcon);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
  };
  imageObjfb.src = 'img/facebook_icon_small.png';

   // add the twitter icon
 var imageObjtwitter = new Image();
  imageObjtwitter.onload = function() {
    var twitterIcon = new Kinetic.Image({
     x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 12,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 84,
      image: imageObjtwitter,
      width: 12,
      height: 10
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    group.add(twitterIcon);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
  };
  imageObjtwitter.src = 'img/twitter_icon_small.png';

   // add the linkedin icon
 var imageObjli = new Image();
  imageObjli.onload = function() {
    var liIcon = new Kinetic.Image({
     x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - -4,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 82,
      image: imageObjli,
      width: 11,
      height: 12
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    group.add(liIcon);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
  };
  imageObjli.src = 'img/linkedin_icon_small.png';

  // add the rss icon
 var imageObjrss = new Image();
  imageObjrss.onload = function() {
    var rssIcon = new Kinetic.Image({
     x: stage.getWidth() / 2 + 20,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 83,
      image: imageObjrss,
      width: 12,
      height: 11
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    group.add(rssIcon);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
  };
  imageObjrss.src = 'img/rss_icon_small.png';

  // add cursor styling
  group.on('mouseover', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  });
 group.on('mouseout', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
  });

  // add the shape to the layer
  group.add(circ);
  group.add(steve);
  group.add(titleText);
  layer.add(group);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);

  steve.src = 'http://braindu.studiophp.net/investors.braindu/img/team_1_p3.png';  // end Steve
```